# What operation is "$\oplus$" in Lounesto's introduction to Clifford Algebras

Tags: complex-numbers, multilinear-algebra, clifford-algebras

I'm reading Lounesto's *CLifford Algebras and Spinors* and on page 26 (also below) he states the following:
\begin{align}
C\mathcal{l}_2=\mathbb{R}\oplus\mathbb{R}^2\oplus\bigwedge^2\mathbb{R}^2.
\end{align}
I see that he states in the prior text a clue, i.e. "the Clifford algebra $C\mathcal{l}_2$ contains copies of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$, and it is the **direct sum** of its subspaces of elements of degrees $0,1,2$..."

How can I think of this (more simply) geometrically, i.e. this "direct sum" of the subspaces?

The page from the text:

[image]

Comment: [Direct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum) [sum](http://science.kennesaw.edu/~sellerme/sfehtml/classes/math3260/directsumsandfundamentalsubspaces.pdf) of vector spaces.

Comment: @Bye_World I see now that this is a simplification of $\bigwedge\mathbb{R}^3=\bigwedge^{\color{red}{0}}\mathbb{R}^3\oplus \bigwedge^{\color{red}{1}}\mathbb{R}^3\oplus\bigwedge^{\color{red}{2}}\mathbb{R}^3\oplus\bigwedge^{\color{red}{3}}\mathbb{R}^3$, since $\bigwedge^0\mathbb{R}^3=\mathbb{R}$ etc. Thanks for the link! I've read that in more advanced algebras this "sum" results in an "object" of the same type as the parts being summed.

Comment: Hmm...perhaps I might only be able to write this as $\bigoplus_{n=0}^3\bigwedge^n\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: Even in this case you get the same type of "object" -- that object being a vector space over the reals.  You can indeed write $\mathcal{Cl}_3 = \bigoplus_{n=0}^3\bigwedge^n\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of $\mathcal{Cl}_2$ as a 4-dimensional vector space, with basis elements $1$, $\mathbf e_1$, $\mathbf e_2$, $\mathbf e_{12}$.  The set of all vectors in $\mathbb R^2$ can then be seen as a two-dimensional subspace of the vector space $\mathcal{Cl}_2$, and the scalars and pseudoscalars each form 1-dimensional subspaces.